# Jetpack Compose: How can I make an expandable/foldable view, containing FlowRow with unknown number of items?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have a FlowRow with an unknown number of items.

I want to wrap this FlowRow with an expandable composable: The expanded height should show all items. The folded view will cover up everything except say, 100.dp.

```
Column {
 FlowLayout() {
   MyItems()
 }
 FlowLayout() {
   MyItems()
 }
}
```

Like so:

[image]

I *have* managed it to get it to work but just by using re-composition:

I use FlowLayout's Modifier.onSizeChanged() and `if size > (wanted folded size)`, then I decrease number of printed "chips" by one.

This means, that if I have 1000 chips to print, this will re-compose 996 times until we have our four chips remaining. It works but I feel it's a hack.

It won't work by just setting the height of the FlowLayout: `FlowLayout(Modifier.heightIn(xxx)) {...}` because FlowLayout will still print all chips, regardless of which size I set as constraint. Furthermore, the layout will then push both up and down! Not just down, from starting point.

Should I be looking into custom Layouts/SubcomposeLayouts?

Comment: Hello! Did you find any solution to implement this behavior?

Comment: @BakiKocak only by using re-composition. And it works well enough so that has been in production since then.